# Windows authentication with user and password in URL Edge/IE mode with Selenium and Java

Tags: security, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I need to open a URL while putting the login and password in the URL like this:

http://login:password@myurl.com

As you know, IE is no longer around.  This requires IE so we are using the new Edge with IE compatibility (where it opens in an IE tab).  Doing this manually (without login and password works fine.  The security box comes up and you enter login and password).  However, doing it with Selenium and Java because I believe when it opens the IE tab it either loses the authority or doesn't send it?  Has anyone else had experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

**`http://login:password@myurl.com`** only works for Basic Authentication. If "Windows authentication" you've mentioned refers to the one which requires **Windows** username and password, then it will not work for you.

A possible workaround could be using JAVA Robot class. Code for reference:

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    driver.navigate().to("myurl.com");
    //Username
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
    //Switch to Password
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    //Password
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    //Submit
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: The problem as I understand it is Robot will not work on Jenkins hub?

Comment: @Tony Emm, yes. You may try alternatives like AutoIt.